# multiple list to tuple

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples

Let' s say we have a multiple list of some values

```
myList = [4,5,[7,[3],4],8]
```

built-in tuple () function will make:

```
myList = (4,5[7,[3],4],8)
```

I think, it needs recursion, the problem is with numbers 4,8 they will dissapear in simple recursion.

The output should be:

```
myList(4,5,(7,(3,),4),8)
```

Comment: So you want the output as `(4,5,(7,(3,),4),8)`?

Comment: why will they disappear in recursion?

Comment: Yes output is good, I sent the n-th list as argument to recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive implementation:

```
myList = [4, 5, [7, [3], 4], 8]

def tuple_recursive(my_list):
    if isinstance(my_list, list):
        return tuple(tuple_recursive(inner) for inner in my_list)
    else:
        return my_list

print tuple_recursive(myList)
```

result:

```
(4, 5, (7, (3,), 4), 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following Recursive function :

```
>>> def convertor(l):
...    return tuple(convertor(tuple(i)) if isinstance(i,list) else i for i in l)
... 
>>> convertor(myList)
(4, 5, (7, (3,), 4), 8)
```